# Visifire - Custom tooltip with more than one binding

Tags: c#, xaml, graph, visifire

I have the object list which i use to create the graph,
in it, I have a X value, Y value and couple of other things (strings, numbers,...) which
describe this object.
I would like to create a custom tooltip who displays them.
I've seen something about binding the Tag property and use it.
But I'm not sure that will fit my needs because as I've said I need more than one property.
Is there any other way I could do it?

BTW I'm using xaml and c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But if you are working with DataBinding, you can map ToolTipText property to each individual DataPoint.

Example:

DataMapping dm = new DataMapping();

dm.MemberName="ToolTipText";

dm.Path = "customToolTipText;

Here customToolTipText is a property in your view model which will have values for each DataPoint in the series.

Example:
customToolTipText = "XValue, YValue, otherdetail...";

This way you can directly set the ToolTipText without relying on ZValue, AxisXLabel etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you explain please, where do i put the data mapping? and how do i use it? just to clearfy: I have a dataseries which and i bind the data source to a object i've created which contains a x value, y value, and a list as well as other values, I want to display all of those in the tool tip (I need a converter for the list).

Comment: Please have a look at the example here.  http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Core_Concepts/Working_with_DataBinding/Creating_Your_First_DataBinding_Sample.htm. In the similar way you can map ToolTipText also.

Answer (score 1):

You can display XValue and YValue inside the ToolTip just by setting ToolTipText property in DataSeries.

Example:

dataSeries.ToolTipText = "#XValue, #YValue";

If you need one more property to store DataPoint's custom information, you can make use of ZValue property in DataSeries. Basically ZValue is useful for Bubble chart but you can utilize it to store some information of DataPoint. Finally display ZValue inside the ToolTip.

Example:

dataSeries.ToolTipText = "#XValue, #YValue, #ZValue";

Comment: what if i need more than one? (i.e. general number of properties)

Comment: You can make use of AxisXLabel property also in DataPoint.